# I am struggling with this chrome extension.Can someone compile it and share

Tags: javascript, html, css, bash, google-chrome-extension

I want to use this extension. I am not into programming. Can someone please compile it and share the ready to use version ...
https://github.com/noitcudni/google-webmaster-tools-bulk-url-removal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Java.

Install leiningen.

Either git clone git@github.com:noitcudni/google-webmaster-tools-bulk-url-removal.git or download the zip file from github and unzip it.

cd into the project root directory.

Run in the terminal - lein release && lein package

Go to chrome://extensions/ and turn on Developer mode.

Click on Load unpacked extension . . . and load the extension.

Comment: Already done but when when adding to chrome  it says "Error - Manifest file is missing or unreadable"

Comment: cd into the project root directory .  just to confirm " here project root directory means 'google-webmaster-tools-bulk-url-removal' folder ?

Comment: "google-webmaster-tools-bulk-url-removal/resources/release" I think this should be the working directory sonce chrome reads the manifest.json file.